# WARN bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?) in AWS SAM

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I am running a `sam local invoke` to called locally an typescript aws lambda function.
This is giving an warning
`2023-04-04T08:53:29.931Z        undefined       WARN    bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)`

Do I need to configure `sam build` to get rid of this warning?

I ran `sam build` and I did not expect this warning.

Answer (score 1):

The error described is unlikely to be connected to AWS SAM, but to the function runtime (or more precisely the build environment).

The warning comes from the `bigint-buffer` NPM library, which uses native C bindings to deal with big numbers in an optimized way. Being C code, it requires certain dependencies to be present to be compiled.

However, `bigint-buffer` will gracefully fallback to the less performant JS implementation in case compiling the C code was not possible. That's why you see the warning.

Despite not being very clear in the `bigint-buffer` documentation, digging a bit deeper will show that the compilation step is managed by another library called `node-gyp`, which requires the following to work properly (according to their [README](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp?tab=readme-ov-file#on-unix)):

- A supported version of `Python`
- `make`
- A proper C/C++ compiler toolchain, like `GCC`

I'm running Debian, so all I needed was to make sure `python3` and `build-essential` (which contains `make` and `gcc`) were installed prior to installing the NPM dependencies.